# Gallery View of Images taken from DB in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have almost 200 images in my List.

```
$rings = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rings WHERE id > ". $ringId ." LIMIT 100");
```

I want to display them in a Gallery form with a Checkbox to each. Each Row must contains atleast 4 images with their checkboxes.

I have tried, making a for loop with adding div but that only adds vertically with on Ring at a time. How can i give it some sort of gallery look.

```
<div>

                                    <?php
                                            echo "<table><tr>";
                                            $i =0;
                                            foreach( $rings as $ring )
                                            {
                                               $i++;
                                               echo '<td><input type="image" src="http://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/vowstore/rings/'.  $ring['imagePath'] .'" name="checked" value="' . $ring['id'].'" data-my-info="'. $ring['ringSetName'] .'" style="width:280px; height:280px;"></td>';
                                               echo '<input type="checkbox">';
                                               if( $i % 3 == 0 )
                                               {
                                                 echo "</tr><tr>";
                                               }
                                             }
                                             echo "</tr></table>";
                                       ?>
                               </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: Please check the edited code, i just want to give it a gallery look that automatically handle the columns according to size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to control the output so that it outputs horizontally until you have 4 images in that row, then start a new row.

Also, might I suggest a table structures for this.

```
echo "<table>
       <tr>";
$i=0;
foreach( $rings as $ring ):
  $i++
  echo "<td><img src='{$ring['thumb']}' /></td>";
  if( $i % 4 == 0 ){
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: yes but this is fixed , is there any way it can be responsive?

Comment: My answer fix this, using responsive grid, not table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider incrementing a variable at each loop, for instance:

```
<?php
    $loop = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $loop++;
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3"><!-- My content --></div>
        <?php
        if ($loop == 4) {
            $loop = 0;
        ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: i also want to add Checkbox on let's say top left corner of image. My images i hvae set them to be 280*280 . how can i put the img on top, check my edited code pls

Comment: It's kind of css stuff, check the "position" property (absolute and relative), with "z-index"